# Using Fluent NHibernate in MVC to map an object in a Create View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use Fluent NHibernate instead of Entity Framework in the MvcMusicStore example and am having a problem populating the ArtistId and GenreId on creating a new album using the Create View. I think it's something to do with the fact i'm referencing other objects

My Album Map is:

```
    public class AlbumMap:ClassMap<Album>
    {
        public AlbumMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.AlbumId);
            Map(x => x.AlbumArtUrl);
            References(x => x.Artist).Cascade.All().Column("ArtistId");
            References(x => x.Genre).Cascade.All().Column("GenreId");
            Map(x => x.Price);
            Map(x => x.Title);
        }
    }
```

The Create method in the controller looks like:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        MusicRepository repository = new MusicRepository();
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(repository.GetArtists(), "ArtistId", "Name");
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(repository.GetGenres(), "GenreId", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

and the part of the Create view which I'm having a problem with is:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre, "Genre")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("GenreId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Artist, "Artist")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ArtistId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Artist)
    </div>
```

In the database, after creating a new Album the other fields such as Title and AlbumUrl are filled in but ArtistId and GenreId are set to null.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably tell I'm quite new to this but I have actually solved my problem. I did this by firstly changing the dropdownlist helpers to dropdownlistfor to enable it to save back:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre, "Genre")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genre.GenreId, (SelectList)ViewBag.GenreId,"Please select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre.GenreId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Artist, "Artist")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Artist.ArtistId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ArtistId,"Please select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Artist.ArtistId)
    </div>
```

This returned me an album with initialised Artist and Genre properties. The only thing was that they only contained Id properties so I had to use these to get the rest of the properties (using nhibernate) before saving:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Album album)
    {
        try
        {
            MusicRepository repository = new MusicRepository();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                album.Artist = repository.GetArtistById(album.Artist.ArtistId);
                album.Genre = repository.GetGenreById(album.Genre.GenreId);
                repository.AddAlbum(album);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }
            ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(repository.GetArtists(), "ArtistId", "Name");
            ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(repository.GetGenres(), "GenreId", "Name");
            return View(album);
        }
```